# Maximum allowed size of OpenReadStream

Tags: blazor

What is the maximum allowed size of OpenReadStream? Right now, using 10MB. But I believe there has to be a certain cap. Can it take GB?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core 5.0, there is a 2 GB framework file size limit for uploading files. However, starting with ASP.NET Core 6.0 and later versions, the framework doesn't impose a maximum file size limit.

By default, files no larger than 512,000 bytes (500 KB) in size are allowed to be read before any further reads would result in an exception. This limit is present to prevent developers from accidentally reading large files into memory.

```cs
await myFile.OpenReadStream().ReadAsync(buffers);
```

To set a custom file upload size, you can override the maxAllowedSize parameter in the OpenReadStream method, as shown below:

```cs
// accept a file upto 307200 bytes (300kb) of size
await myFile.OpenReadStream(maxAllowedSize: 1024 * 300).ReadAsync(buffers);
```

---

**UPDATE:**
I tested the file upload with a file that is 2 GB in size, and it was uploaded successfully.

**DEMO:**

[image: Image showing upload of 2GB file using Blazor Server]

**CODE:**
This Blazor Server code example has been updated to work with .NET Framework 7 and Visual Studio 2022, and it uses the `long` data type to represent the file size accurately. This is essential when working with files larger than 2 GB, which can't be represented by an `int`.

```razor
@page "/"
@using System.IO
@inject IWebHostEnvironment env

<h1 class="mb-4">Blazor Server File Upload</h1>

<div class="@AlertClass" role="alert">
    @AlertMessage
</div>

<div class="progress mb-3" style="height: 20px;">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: @ProgressPercentage%;" aria-valuenow="@ProgressPercentage" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">@ProgressPercentage% Complete</div>
</div>

<form @onsubmit="OnSubmit" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <InputFile @key=@(inputFileId) class="form-control" id="inputFile" OnChange="OnInputFileChange" aria-describedby="uploadButton" required />
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="uploadButton" disabled="@IsUploadDisabled">
            <span class="oi oi-cloud-upload" aria-hidden="true"></span> Upload Selected File
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please select a file to upload.
    </div>
</form>

@code {
    MarkupString AlertMessage = new MarkupString("<strong>No file selected</strong>");
    string AlertClass = "alert alert-info";
    int ProgressPercentage = 0;
    IBrowserFile selectedFile;
    long maxFileSize = 1024L * 1024L * 1024L * 2L;
    string[] allowedExtensions = { ".zip", ".rar", ".bin"};
    bool IsUploadDisabled = true;
    private Guid inputFileId = Guid.NewGuid();

    private void OnInputFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedFile = e.GetMultipleFiles()[0];
        ProgressPercentage = 0;
        IsUploadDisabled = true;

        if (selectedFile.Size > maxFileSize)
        {
            SetAlert("alert alert-danger", "oi oi-ban", $"File size exceeds the limit. Maximum allowed size is <strong>{maxFileSize / (1024 * 1024)} MB</strong>.");
            return;
        }

        if (!allowedExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(selectedFile.Name).ToLowerInvariant()))
        {
            SetAlert("alert alert-danger", "oi oi-warning", $"Invalid file type. Allowed file types are <strong>{string.Join(", ", allowedExtensions)}</strong>.");
            return;
        }

        SetAlert("alert alert-info", "oi oi-info", $"<strong>{selectedFile.Name}</strong> ({selectedFile.Size} bytes) file selected.");
        IsUploadDisabled = false;
    }

    private async void OnSubmit()
    {
        if (selectedFile != null)
        {
            IsUploadDisabled = true;
            Stream stream = selectedFile.OpenReadStream(maxFileSize);
            var path = $"{env.WebRootPath}\\{selectedFile.Name}";
            using FileStream fs = File.Create(path);

            // Set buffer size to 512 KB.
            int bufferSize = 512 * 1024;
            byte[] buffer = System.Buffers.ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(bufferSize);
            int bytesRead;
            long totalBytesRead = 0;
            long fileSize = selectedFile.Size;

            // Use a timer to update the UI every few hundred milliseconds.
            using var timer = new Timer(_ => InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged()));
            timer.Change(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));

            try
            {
                while ((bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer)) != 0)
                {
                    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                    ProgressPercentage = (int)(100 * totalBytesRead / fileSize);
                    await fs.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                System.Buffers.ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(buffer);
            }

            // Stop the timer and update the UI with the final progress.
            timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
            ProgressPercentage = 100;
            SetAlert("alert alert-success", "oi oi-check", $"<strong>{selectedFile.Name}</strong> ({selectedFile.Size} bytes) file uploaded on server.");
            inputFileId = Guid.NewGuid();
            this.StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

    private void SetAlert(string alertClass, string iconClass, string message)
    {
        AlertClass = alertClass;
        AlertMessage = new MarkupString($"<span class='{iconClass}' aria-hidden='true'></span> {message}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, I believe for 2GB, saying loadedFile.OpenReadStream(maxAllowedSize: 1024 * 1024 * 2000) would suffice?

Comment: @Sarahrb Yes I can say it works. I didn't have a 2Gb file nearby, I tried with a 1.9Gb and it was uploaded. It takes longer though.

Comment: @Sarahrb I have updated my answer to show the result.

Comment: 2GB = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 2 bytes

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos I updated my answer to include your input. Thank you.

Comment: Btw, the 2GB limit has been removed in .NET 6. Relevant GitHub issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/33638

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos Thanks for letting me know. I updated that in the answer.