# Load large file in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

I am trying to upload large files (regardless of file type) into SQL Server database.

But when I upload a large one (at least 13.2MB or more) it appears the next error message:

> System.IO.IOException: Supplied file with size 13897053 bytes exceeds the maximum of 512000 bytes.

When the user uploads the files I call the next method to save the files into `IList<IBrowserFile>`.

```
private IList<IBrowserFile> Files = new List<IBrowserFile>();
private int MaxAllowdFiles = int.MaxValue;
private long MaxSizeFiles = long.MaxValue;

private async Task OnInputFileChanged(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        ClearDragClass();
        /*var files = e.GetMultipleFiles();
        foreach(var file in files)
        {
            Files.Add(file);
            Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFullPath(file.Name));
        }*/

        //using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

        foreach (var file in e.GetMultipleFiles(MaxAllowdFiles))
        {
            using var f = file.OpenReadStream(MaxSizeFiles);
            using var fileContent = new StreamContent(f);
            fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(file.ContentType);

            Files.Add(file);
        }
    }
```

Once the user has uploaded all the files, they click on a button that call the next method to upload it into a database.

```
private async void Upload()
    {
        List<string>? notUploadFiles = new();
        foreach (var file in Files)
        {
            using Stream s = file.OpenReadStream();
            using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            await s.CopyToAsync(ms);
            byte[] fileBytes = ms.ToArray();

            string extn = new FileInfo(file.Name).Extension;

            var addArchivoTarea = new AddArchivoTareaRequestDTO(Tarea.Id, file.Name, fileBytes, extn);
            var successResponse = await HttpTareas.AddArchivoToTareaAsync(addArchivoTarea);

            if (!successResponse)
            {
                notUploadFiles.Add(file.Name);
            }
        }

        if (notUploadFiles.Count > 0)
        {
            Snackbar.Configuration.SnackbarVariant = Variant.Filled;
            Snackbar.Add("The following files could not be uploaded", Severity.Info);

            Snackbar.Configuration.SnackbarVariant = Variant.Outlined;
            foreach (var file in notUploadFiles)
            {
                Snackbar.Add(file, Severity.Error);
            }
            MudDialog.Close(DialogResult.Ok(true));
        }

        Snackbar.Add("All files have been successfully uploaded", Severity.Success);
        MudDialog.Close(DialogResult.Ok(true));
    }
```

I don't know what I should add or modify to be able to upload large files. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Try to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74041370/maximum-allowed-size-of-openreadstream , there is a keyword ```maxAllowedSize```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server#inputfile-component)

> OpenReadStream enforces a maximum size in bytes of its Stream. Reading
> one file or multiple files larger than 500 KB results in an exception.
> This limit prevents developers from accidentally reading large files
> into memory. The maxAllowedSize parameter of OpenReadStream can be
> used to specify a larger size if required up to a maximum supported
> size of 2 GB.

so you can have:

```
 Stream s = file.OpenReadStream (maxAllowedSize :[the value you prefer]);
```