# Sending big amount of data to Blazor Server

Tags: .net-6.0, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-6.0

I have ASP.NET MVC (.NET6) project. Inside, we created Server Side Blazor hub (`services.AddServerSideBlazor();`  and `app.MapBlazorHub();`) and we successfully integrated several components.

When showing some data in the UI, we save it on the client (session storage of the browser) using `ProtectedSessionStorage`  class and its methods `GetAsync/ SetAsync`. Everything is working good, but we encountered an issue. Some of the information in the session storage is too big.
So, for those of you who have experience with Server Blazor - it is not sensitive to data amount (in terms of bytes) which it sends to the client. But it is sensitive to the (external) data that the client tries to send back to the server.
In my case, the data saved on the client exceeds the standard 32kb of the `AddHubOptions` property `MaximumReceiveMessageSize`. It is an encryption string, containing encrypted json objects.

There are examples of uploading a file through a form, in the official MS Docs. I was wondering if there is a way to stream the information from the session storage to the server, without touching the `MaximumRecieveMessageSize` , since making the threshold too big can create security holes.

Also, if I set a hardcoded limit of for example 300kb, would it be enough for a DoS attack?

Comment: You can have  a try [IFormFile.OpenReadStream Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile.openreadstream?view=aspnetcore-7.0). Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74041370/maximum-allowed-size-of-openreadstream) .